# Mongodb aggregation in Python : cannot pickle 'SSLContext' object

Tags: python, django, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I need to find count of same groups (like count of same colour products or same price products)  and I try to do aggreagtion using '$group'.

```
result = collection.aggregate(
                            [
                            {
                                "$group" : {"_id":group_aggregation_format, "count": 
                                           {"$sum":1}}
                            }
                            ])
print(result)
```

group_aggreagtion_format is a data like {'title': '$title', 'colour': '$colour'}

Then I get this error

```
| INFO:dill:# T4
web_1            | D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3bfbe40>
web_1            | INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3bfbe40>
web_1            | T4: <class 'pymongo.client_options.ClientOptions'>
web_1            | INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.client_options.ClientOptions'>
web_1            | # T4
web_1            | INFO:dill:# T4
web_1            | D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3c13dc0>
web_1            | INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3c13dc0>
web_1            | T4: <class 'pymongo.common._CaseInsensitiveDictionary'>
web_1            | INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.common._CaseInsensitiveDictionary'>
web_1            | # T4
web_1            | INFO:dill:# T4
web_1            | D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3b84f00>
web_1            | INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3b84f00>
web_1            | D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3a79240>
web_1            | INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3a79240>
web_1            | # D2
web_1            | INFO:dill:# D2
web_1            | D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3bbfc40>
web_1            | INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7efec3bbfc40>
web_1            | # D2
web_1            | INFO:dill:# D2
web_1            | # D2
web_1            | INFO:dill:# D2
web_1            | T6: <class 'pymongo.auth.MongoCredential'>
web_1            | INFO:dill:T6: <class 'pymongo.auth.MongoCredential'>
web_1            | # T6
web_1            | INFO:dill:# T6
web_1            | T4: <class 'pymongo.auth._Cache'>
web_1            | INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.auth._Cache'>
web_1            | # T4
web_1            | INFO:dill:# T4
web_1            | D2: <dict object at 0x7efea14a0c80>
web_1            | INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7efea14a0c80>
web_1            | # D2
web_1            | INFO:dill:# D2
web_1            | T4: <class 'pymongo.pool.PoolOptions'>
web_1            | INFO:dill:T4: <class 'pymongo.pool.PoolOptions'>
web_1            | # T4
web_1            | INFO:dill:# T4
web_1            | D2: <dict object at 0x7efea1524d80>
web_1            | INFO:dill:D2: <dict object at 0x7efea1524d80>
web_1            | cannot pickle 'SSLContext' object
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? Is it the way I am doing aggregation? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly not your query per se; the issue will be with how you are creating the connection (MongoClient).

pymongo doesn't make a server connection until you execute the first database command, so even though the error is on the aggregate command, the issue is further upstream in your code.